# How to drop oracle partitions?

Tags: sql, oracle, partitioning

I have a requirement, we are creating partitions on daily basis on date so, need to drop older partitions which are older than 30 days.

Is there any best approach to drop partition without using alter drop command?
Can we set expiry date or time on partition which drop the partitions?

Comment: No Ravi, there is no option like automatic drop partition. You need to use the drop command to drop any unused partition.

Answer (score 0):

**partition_number** is a number of partition/day you can keep

**table_name** table name with partition

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE REMOVE_OLD_PARTITIONS(table_nameIN VARCHAR2, partition_number NUMBER) IS
    stm           VARCHAR2(100);
    last_partition NUMBER;

BEGIN
    BEGIN
        SELECT MAX(PARTITION_POSITION)
        INTO last_partition 
        FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS
        WHERE TABLE_NAME = table_name;
       
        FOR cur1 IN (SELECT PARTITION_NAME AS part2drop
                     FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS
                     WHERE TABLE_NAME = table_name
                       AND PARTITION_POSITION > 1
                       AND PARTITION_POSITION <= last_partition - partition_number)
            LOOP
                stm := 'alter table ' || table_name|| ' drop partition "' || cur1.part2drop || '"';

                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stm;
            END LOOP;
    END;

END;
```

You can exec this procedure with job every day.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting up a RETENTION table for each PARTITION table. Once the RETENTION period has passed then you can drop the PARTITION.

This should be a scheduled task. In addition, I found this code in stackoverflow, which renames system GENERATED PARTITION to something meaningful.

```
CREATE TABLE PARTITION_RETENTION (
   seq_num NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
    TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(30),
    RETENTION INTERVAL DAY(3) TO SECOND(0),
 CONSTRAINT
partition_retention_pk primary key (table_name),
CONSTRAINT CHK_NON_ZERO_DAYS CHECK (
        RETENTION > INTERVAL '0' DAY
    ),
    CONSTRAINT CHK_WHOLE_DAYS CHECK (
        EXTRACT(HOUR FROM RETENTION) = 0
        AND EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM RETENTION) = 0
        AND EXTRACT(SECOND FROM RETENTION) = 0
    )
);

insert into PARTITION_RETENTION (TABLE_NAME, RETENTION) 
select 'T1', interval '10' day from dual union all
select 'T3', interval '15' day from dual union all
select 'T4', 15 * interval '1' day from dual union all
select 'T5', 5 * interval '1 00:00:00' day to second from dual;



/* test data */

CREATE TABLE t0 (     
 seq_num NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
   dt   DATE
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (dt)  
INTERVAL 
(NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1,'YEAR'))
(
   PARTITION OLD_DATA values LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2020-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
);
/

INSERT into t0 (dt)
with dt (dt, interv) as (
select date '2021-01-01', numtodsinterval(90,'DAY') from dual
union all
select dt.dt + interv, interv from dt
where dt.dt + interv < date '2028-12-31')
select dt from dt;
/

CREATE TABLE t1 (     
 seq_num NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
   dt   DATE
)
PARTITION BY RANGE (dt)
INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(7,'DAY'))
(
   PARTITION OLD_DATA values LESS THAN (TO_DATE('2022-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'))
);
/

INSERT into t1 (dt)
with dt (dt, interv) as (
select date '2022-01-01', numtodsinterval(1,'DAY') from dual
union all
select dt.dt + interv, interv from dt
where dt.dt + interv < date '2022-07-31')
select dt from dt;
/

INSERT into t1 (dt)
SELECT DATE '2022-01-01'
       + DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, DATE '2022-01-31' - DATE '2022-01-01' + 1)
FROM   DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL<=100;
/

create index t1_global_ix on t1 (dt);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ddl(p_cmd varchar2) 
 authid current_user
is
t1 pls_integer;
BEGIN 
t1 := dbms_utility.get_time; 

dbms_output.put_line(p_cmd);

 execute immediate p_cmd;

dbms_output.put_line((dbms_utility.get_time - t1)/100 || ' seconds');

END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE rebuild_index
authid current_user
is

BEGIN 
        for i in (
            select index_owner, index_name, partition_name, 'partition' ddl_type
           from all_ind_partitions
           where status = 'UNUSABLE'
           union all
           select owner, index_name, null, null
           from all_indexes
           where status = 'UNUSABLE'
       )
       loop
         if i.ddl_type is null then
          ddl('alter index '||i.index_owner||'.'||i.index_name||' rebuild parallel 4 online');
         else
          ddl('alter index '||i.index_owner||'.'||i.index_name||' modify '||i.ddl_type||' '||i.partition_name||' rebuild parallel 4 online');
         end if;
       end loop;
 END;
/

/* Schedule this task daily 
rename system GENERATED PARTITION  to something meaningful 
*/

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MaintainPartitions IS  EXPRESSION_IS_OF_WRONG_TYPE EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(EXPRESSION_IS_OF_WRONG_TYPE, -6550);

    CURSOR PartTables IS
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, INTERVAL
    FROM USER_PART_TABLES 
    WHERE PARTITIONING_TYPE = 'RANGE' 
    ORDER BY TABLE_NAME;

    CURSOR TabParts(aTableName VARCHAR2) IS 
    SELECT PARTITION_NAME, HIGH_VALUE
    FROM USER_TAB_PARTITIONS
 WHERE regexp_like(partition_name,'^SYS_P[[:digit:]]{1,10}')  AND
 TABLE_NAME = aTableName AND
table_name not like 'BIN$%'
      and    interval is not null
    ORDER BY PARTITION_POSITION;

    ym INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH;
    ds INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND;
    newPartName VARCHAR2(30);
    PERIOD TIMESTAMP;

BEGIN

    FOR aTab IN PartTables LOOP 
        BEGIN       
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := '||aTab.INTERVAL||'; END;' USING OUT ds;
            ym := NULL; 
        EXCEPTION 
            WHEN EXPRESSION_IS_OF_WRONG_TYPE THEN
                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := '||aTab.INTERVAL||'; END;' USING OUT ym;
                ds := NULL;         
        END;            

        FOR aPart IN TabParts(aTab.TABLE_NAME) LOOP         
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := '||aPart.HIGH_VALUE||'; END;' USING OUT PERIOD;
            IF ds IS NOT NULL THEN
                IF ds >= INTERVAL '7' DAY THEN
                    -- Weekly partition
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := TO_CHAR('||aPart.HIGH_VALUE||' - :int, :fmt); END;' USING OUT newPartName, INTERVAL '1' DAY, '"P_"IYYY"W"IW';
                ELSE
                    -- Daily partition
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := TO_CHAR('||aPart.HIGH_VALUE||' - :int, :fmt); END;' USING OUT newPartName, INTERVAL '1' DAY, '"P_"YYYYMMDD';
                END IF;
            ELSE
                IF ym = INTERVAL '3' MONTH THEN
                    -- Quarterly partition 
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := TO_CHAR('||aPart.HIGH_VALUE||' - :int, :fmt); END;' USING OUT newPartName, INTERVAL '1' DAY, '"P_"YYYY"Q"Q';
                ELSE
                    -- Monthly partition
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := TO_CHAR('||aPart.HIGH_VALUE||' - :int, :fmt); END;' USING OUT newPartName, INTERVAL '1' DAY, '"P_"YYYYMM';
                END IF;
            END IF;

            IF newPartName <> aPart.PARTITION_NAME THEN
                EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||aTab.TABLE_NAME||' RENAME PARTITION '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME||' TO '||newPartName;
            END IF;             
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;

END MaintainPartitions;
/


/* schedule this task */

DECLARE
    CANNOT_DROP_LAST_PARTITION EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(CANNOT_DROP_LAST_PARTITION, -14758);

    CANNOT_DROP_ONLY_ONE_PARTITION EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(CANNOT_DROP_ONLY_ONE_PARTITION, -14083);

   ts TIMESTAMP;
 
   CURSOR TablePartitions IS
    SELECT TABLE_NAME, PARTITION_NAME, p.HIGH_VALUE, t.INTERVAL, RETENTION, DATA_TYPE
    FROM USER_PART_TABLES t
        JOIN USER_TAB_PARTITIONS p USING (TABLE_NAME)
        JOIN USER_PART_KEY_COLUMNS pk ON pk.NAME = TABLE_NAME
        JOIN USER_TAB_COLS tc USING (TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME)
        JOIN PARTITION_RETENTION r USING (TABLE_NAME)
    WHERE        pk.object_type     = 'TABLE' AND
   t.partitioning_type = 'RANGE' AND 
    REGEXP_LIKE (tc.data_type, '^DATE$|^TIMESTAMP.*'); 

BEGIN

    FOR aPart IN TablePartitions LOOP
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'BEGIN :ret := '||aPart.HIGH_VALUE||'; END;' USING OUT ts;
        IF ts < SYSTIMESTAMP - aPart.RETENTION THEN
            BEGIN
             ddl('alter table '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' drop partition '||aPart.partition_name);
 
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN CANNOT_DROP_ONLY_ONE_PARTITION THEN
                    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cant drop the only partition '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME ||' from table '||aPart.TABLE_NAME);
  
   ddl('ALTER TABLE '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' TRUNCATE PARTITION '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME);
                                                   WHEN CANNOT_DROP_LAST_PARTITION THEN
                    BEGIN
                        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Drop last partition '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME ||' from table '||aPart.TABLE_NAME);
                        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' SET INTERVAL ()';
 
 ddl('alter table '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' drop partition '||aPart.partition_name);

                        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' SET INTERVAL( '||aPart.INTERVAL||' )';            
                    EXCEPTION
                        WHEN CANNOT_DROP_ONLY_ONE_PARTITION THEN 
                            -- Depending on the order the "last" partition can be also the "only" partition at the same time
                                                 
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' SET INTERVAL( '||aPart.INTERVAL||' )';    

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cant drop the only partition '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME ||' from table '||aPart.TABLE_NAME);
  
         ddl('ALTER TABLE '||aPart.TABLE_NAME||' TRUNCATE PARTITION '||aPart.PARTITION_NAME);                
               END;
            END;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
   rebuild_index();
END;
```